# Are there any Turkish grammar apps/website that allow for more interactive Turkish grammar and translation training?

Tags: turkic-languages

I have been trying to learn Turkish for a while now. I studied most of my grammar book, made most of the exercises in it and translated all the Turkish sentences I encountered in the book (and practiced translating these from English to Turkish). That all went pretty well, but when I tried reading some kids books afterwards I noticed they were still too difficult! On top of that, I always forget Turkish grammar when I put it aside for a while - which I mostly do due to me being disappointed over my progress.

I am now a bit tired of studying the way I used to do, but I have to study because my family in law is Turkish (I don't live in Turkey). I was therefore wondering whether there is an app or website that teaches Turkish a bit more like a game. I would like to have something that gradually builds up and where I don't have the feeling that I have to wrestle myself through long sections of grammar and exercises.

For instance, a grammatical rule is explained and then one question needs to be answered before you can go on to the next one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duolingo a popular gamified language learning website/application: https://www.duolingo.com/course/tr/en/Learn-Turkish-Online

It teaches grammar by translation of sentences. On the web interface you can also find short information blurbs about grammar, if these have been written for Turkish.

I have mostly used Duolingo to learn languages where I already had studied (and forgotten) most of the grammar, and it worked well as a refreshment/reintroduction. It also teaches accuracy in writing and, for most courses, a somewhat peculiar set of vocabulary. For me, it does not work as a means of learning good pronunciation or listening skills, though it does help a little.

Children's book are good in that they are often easy to follow and have pictures, but they can be challenging in that the vocabulary there is typically not taught to adult learners very actively. You might want to ask a separate question about how to get started with them.

Also, you might want to not put things aside for a while, but rather integrate continuous language learning into your schedule, up to the amount you can, so that there are very few long stretches without exposure. Marathon, not a sprint.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, @Tommi Brander. I am now using duolingo to learn Turkish, Spanish, German, Hungarian and Swedish. I like it a lot - I think I might be a bit over ambitious :)

Answer (score 0):

I think clozemaster (or tatoeba) is a bit better suited than duolingo as you are already familiar with the grammar and just need to practice your reading skills